# Jenkins: nexusArtifactUploader is auto-renaming my zip file while uploading to nexus

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I have a jenkins pipeline, that will upload my artifact (a zip file) to nexus.
For this I am using **nexusArtifactUploader**.
While doing so, the nexusArtifactUploader is renamin my zip file by appending the date-time and some digits at the end, whereas I want to retain the actual name of my file as is.
Snippet:

```
nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: [[artifactId: 'my_project_load', classifier: '', file: '/apps/external/5/jenkins-node-home/workspace/my_project_load_load-0.1.29-SNAPSHOT.zip', type: 'zip']], credentialsId: 'Aiman_Sarosh_cred', groupId: 'com.group.id', nexusUrl: 'nexus.com/nexus', nexusVersion: 'nexus2', protocol: 'https', repository: 'ict-snapshots', version: '0.1.29-SNAPSHOT'
```

And I am getting this:

```
16:59:14  Uploading: https://nexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/content/repositories/ict-snapshots/com/group/id/my_project_load-0.1.29-SNAPSHOT/0.1.29-SNAPSHOT/my_project_load-0.1.29-SNAPSHOT-0.1.29-20230922.112914-1.zip
```

How should I handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

That's [how Nexus works](https://community.sonatype.com/t/what-is-the-differences-between-maven-baseversion-and-maven-version/2937).

This `my_project_load-0.1.29-SNAPSHOT-0.1.29-20230922.112914-1`,
is: `<ARTIFACT>-<VERSION>[-SNAPSHOT<-TIMESTAMP-INCREMENT>]`.

Nexus stores every `SNAPSHOT` upload with a timestamp and incremental counter. But maven will always serve you the latest when you specify `-SNAPSHOT`. (That's also why there are [cleanup policies](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/tasks/maven-snapshot-tasks#MavenSNAPSHOTTasks-DeleteSNAPSHOTTaskExample) for SNAPSHOTs.

If you want to keep the number you upload, you need to supply the release version number (ie: `0.1.29`) and not use -SNAPSHOT.